# Data synchronization between REST services

Tags: rest

As I know REST architecture consists of "frontend" - server which receives requests from clients, and services which are actual "backend" - all business logic and data stored in services(which are exactly same application, which runs at same time on multiple servers). If every service has it's own data storage then how data synchronized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each service has a data set and the synchronization can be established with differents ways. Please view the example bellow.

Service A - Products - ProductDB

Service B - Users - UserDB

If a user wants to get all the products for the users with black hairs (for example) this will be a common process that will system follow:

1) Receive the request from client in Gateway

2) Go to user service and the users with black hairs.

`select * from users where hair_color='black'`

3) Now the user service sends the users IDs to the product service. So the product service executes the following query.

`select * from product where user_id IN $(userIds)`

4) Finally, the products return to the client.

Please read about gateway https://www.nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/

Comment: Thank you for response, but it's not quite what I meant. Even with gateway, if there are multiple instances of Service A on different servers each with it's own database, and on one of them data changed, how other instances of Service A on other servers synchronize their databases? Is there any library for that, or this should be done manually?

Comment: all the services A will look to the same database !!!!!!!! but a service B cannot look to service A database. Please read about micro services architecture designs.

Comment: I found an answer already.  Here  http://realscale.cloud66.com/database-server-scaling-strategies/ multiple databases for each app, but those are read-only.(#1 Read replicas)